CollectionViewCell updating wrong after scrolling
I have a collection view that lists a number of items that initially are not selected. If the user taps on them, a border appears around the element and the id for that element is added to an array. If the same element is tapped, then the border disappears and the element is removed from the array. I have set up the collection view like this:
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: InterestsCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! InterestsCollectionViewCell
    
    let viewModel = interestsViewModels[indexPath.row]
    
    let imageURL = URL(string: viewModel.imageName)
    
    cell.configure(url: imageURL!, name: viewModel.topicName)
    
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    
    
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! InterestsCollectionViewCell
    
    cell.toggleActive()
    
    let interest = interests[indexPath.row]
    if cell.hasBorder {
        selectedInterests.append(interest.topicId)
    } else {
        if let index = selectedInterests.firstIndex(of: interest.topicId) {
            selectedInterests.remove(at: index)
        }
    }
}

In the InterestsCollectionViewCell I have these methods:
var hasBorder = false

func configure(url: URL, name: String) {
    itemImageView.sd_imageIndicator = SDWebImageActivityIndicator.medium
    itemImageView.sd_setImage(with: url, placeholderImage: nil, options: .refreshCached)
}

func toggleActive() {
    if !hasBorder {
        itemBorderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor(named: "interestBorder")?.cgColor
        hasBorder = true
    } else {
        itemBorderView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        hasBorder = false
    }
}

The problem is that when I scroll, then random cells start to appear with or without borders. I understand this issue happens because the cells are being reused, but I can't find a way of setting this up without this happening.
I tried doing the following in didSelectItemAt:
let interest = interests[indexPath.row]
interest.selected.toggle()

And then passing interest.selected to toggleActive() but not only did the problem continue, but I was never able to update the value of interest.selected. Every time I clicked it took it initially as false.
How can I set this up correctly?

Cells are reused. You need to set the border and remove it in cellForItemAt or set the border in previous method and remove the border in prepareForReuse.

The cell should not be used to save hasBorder state. It must be saved somewhere by the collection view controller. When configuring a cell, you should set or hide the border . When toggling, modify your state and reload the cell or the table view.
